# iTunesConnect Export compliance questions - Does my ios application contain encryption?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, app-store, app-store-connect

I am about to submit my first iOS application to the AppStore and I am faced with several questions about export compliance.

There are two points that made me wonder whether my application contains encryption or not?

- I am using AdMob for advertising (banners etc.)
- I ask users to rate my app. If they say OK, then I use this code;

  ```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kAppStoreAddress]];
  ```

I am confused what to answer on export compliance questions...

Comment: What does launching a URL or using AdMob have to do with encryption?

Comment: Potentially the URL might be https or redirect to https. Yeah stupid. https used encryption, both PKI and symmetric. You make a http request that is redirected to a https connection, this is not uncommon.

Comment: Launching `https` URLs doesn't require saying "YES" to using encryption as far as I know. It's not your app using `https` at that point, it's Safari (which is launched to handle the URL).

Comment: Good point if it is Safari or another app that would be not using encryption. If it is your app that is different.

Comment: Just for completeness: In the OP's instance there is no export issue because the app does not itself use https. In the instance that an app does make https requests, even through a redirect, the question must be answered that encryption is used. Source: I asked two cryptographic domain experts (both CISSPs) this question and was told that without doubt that is using encryption as defined by BIS (Bureau of Industry and Security).